# Community Wiki article about shrinking Windows 7 for SSD

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I would like to create Community Wiki question about shrinking Windows 7 for SSD drives.

SSD drives become cheap, many people ask about this and there is no single thread about this.

Today I wrote pretty big answer about this:

[Reducing system disk space usage on computer with SQL Server](https://superuser.com/questions/842526/reducing-system-disk-space-usage-on-computer-with-sql-server/842540#842540)

**Shall I create such article or this is bad idea?**

**What title would be better? "What can I do to save space on SSD with Windows 7" or maybe something else?**

I had some question block issue for stupid reason and I don't want to risk question ban again. This is why I'm asking here first.

Comment: We have couple of such posts. http://superuser.com/questions/8141/reclaiming-disk-space-on-windows http://superuser.com/questions/61880/windows-7-missing-free-hdd-space

Comment: But this is about reclaiming or missing space. I would like to create something about system preparation for SSD.

Comment: I think the end result is the same.

Comment: @Kamil - I personally think you should do it.  Often times there are better ways to do it.  I suggest you stick to one of the newer versions of Windows but verify it still works on versions after it of course.  The process of moving all of an operating systems files to the front end of a drive, is hard enough even on a normal HDD, you might even considering just explaining how to shrink the Windows installation sticking to good supported methods ( i.e. none of that non-sense of removing `WinSxS` directory

Comment: @Ramhound Im considering sticking to few latest Windows versions (Vista, 7, 8), because they are very similar and all methods known to me will work.

Comment: @Kamil - Well I personally think it is a good idea.  The problem you might have is the grammar will need to be absolutely perfect can you handle that?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think he'll need to worry *that* much about grammar. There are plenty of people here that can help with that.